# Preventing Adsense Crawling Specific Regions of the Site

Tags: google-adsense, googlebot

In my website, I wan't adsense crawler to not consider certain parts of the HTML. Is there any snippet I can use. The reason is I am using a plugin from an external provider and as soon as I installed that plugin, adsense stopped showing relevant ads and started showing ads related to that plugin.

```
<!--Adsense Should Crawl -->
    My Content
<!--Adsense Should Crawl -->

<!--Adsense Should NOT Crawl -->
    Private Content
<!--Adsense Should NOT Crawl -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [section targeting](http://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=23168):

```
<!-- google_ad_section_start(weight=ignore) -->
[stuff to ignore here]
<!-- google_ad_section_end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Google adsense displays adds relevant for the viewer. You maybe seeing different adds from those that your web site users see. One feature I've noticed recently is that after visiting certain web pages, all the adverts on every page I visit suddenly become adverts for that site. So you might be seeing adverts for that plug-in because you visited that plug-in's page, not because of the website content.

Try clearing your browser data including cookies and see if the adverts change. Killing the cookies should remove googles stored data about you and ensure that you only see adverts based on the page content.

Comment: Yes. I too observed this trend. Its good actually, for the visitors.