# How to tell Google to crawl distinct part of the webpage?

Tags: seo, google

What approach should I take to make the website Google-friendly, http://anuary.com/.

The problem is that when a specific content is being requested (eg. http://anuary.com/1/home/anuary) user is taken to the page using scrollbar, though the surrounding content is still being loaded. How to tell Google that for this URL http://anuary.com/36/portfolio/three-musketeers only the #36 entry should be crawled.

Is there a tag or other way to select the surrounding content as irrelevant for the URL?

Comment: You cannot do this. Google will more or less see what you see when you look at source code of that page. There is no way to tell Googlebot to not consider the structure of the page, you can only tell Googlebot to ignore entire pages/sections.

Comment: See also: [Preventing robots from crawling specific part of a page](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page)

Answer (score 5):

It's [not possible](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/TB68WpnGuos) to tell GoogleBot to not/crawl portions of your documents. The bot takes it all in and they decide what they think is important. Only AdSense allows for [section targeting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17226/preventing-adsense-crawling-specific-regions-of-the-site/17228#17228).

As far as I can tell, GoogleBot isn't doing anything wrong. The problem is that your URLs aren't real in the first place. You have a giant document and you're using a fake sub-directory structure that you use to figure out how far down to scroll via something that seems to pretend to be Ajax. If you were *actually* using it, then you could follow the [crawling guidelines](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992)

Answer (score -2):

Google provides `googleon/googleof` tags that are just right for the job ( https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/46/admin_crawl/Preparing ). An explanation on how to use them is available at http://perishablepress.com/tell-google-to-not-index-certain-parts-of-your-page/.

Though, essentially it all comes to:

```
<!--googleoff: all-->
This content will not be indexed.
<!--googleon: all>
```

Comment: -1 That's for the search appliance.

Comment: `googleoff` and `googleon` [only work with the Google search appliance and have no effect on normal Googlebot](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54735/can-you-use-googleon-and-googleoff-comments-to-prevent-googlebot-from-indexing-p)